# XQUERY: How to search for XML tag with multiple name values

Tags: xquery

I'm new to XQuery.

I have two files- input.xml and config.xml,  I want to be able to search the input.xml file and check if ALL config.xml soffs are in the input.xml

Using the example below, I want to check if soff=ABC and soff=DEF and soff=GHI exist in input.xml and if all three are found in the input.xml I want to return the subscribergroup value in the config.xml  *WITHOUT HARDCODING*

Here's my input.xml ...

```
<SOFF SOFNO="3732" NAME="ABC" ACTION="X">
      <OPNOKEY>
        <OPNO>00042</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00045</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00069</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00103</OPNO>
     </OPNOKEY>
      <PARMS QTY="3">
        <PARM NAME="#NEW" VALUE="3" ACTION="A"/>
        <PARM NAME="#NEW" VALUE="0" ACTION="R"/>
        <PARM NAME="#OLD" VALUE="3" ACTION="X"/>
      </PARMS>
      <ATTRS QTY="0"/>
    </SOFF>
    <SOFF SOFNO="3735" NAME="DEF" ACTION="R">
      <OPNOKEY>
        <OPNO>00042</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00045</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00069</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00103</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00104</OPNO>
     </OPNOKEY>
      <PARMS QTY="1">
        <PARM NAME="INSTL" VALUE="GHI" ACTION="R"/>
      </PARMS>
      <ATTRS QTY="0"/>
    </SOFF>
    <SOFF SOFNO="2959" NAME="STB3" ACTION="R">
      <OPNOKEY>
        <OPNO>00042</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00045</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00069</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00103</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00104</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00105</OPNO>
      </OPNOKEY>
       <PARMS QTY="0"/>
      <ATTRS QTY="0"/>
    </SOFF>
    <SOFF SOFNO="2958" NAME="JKL" ACTION="R">
      <OPNOKEY>
        <OPNO>00042</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00045</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00069</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00103</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00104</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00106</OPNO>
      </OPNOKEY>
      <PARMS QTY="0"/>
      <ATTRS QTY="0"/>
    </SOFF>
    <SOFF SOFNO="2957" NAME="MNO" ACTION="R">
      <OPNOKEY>
        <OPNO>00042</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00045</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00069</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00103</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00104</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00107</OPNO>
      </OPNOKEY>
      <PARMS QTY="0"/>
      <ATTRS QTY="0"/>
    </SOFF>
    <SOFF SOFNO="3349" NAME="PQR" ACTION="A">
      <OPNOKEY>
        <OPNO>00042</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00045</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00069</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00103</OPNO>
        <OPNO>00110</OPNO>
     </OPNOKEY>
      <PARMS QTY="0"/>
      <ATTRS QTY="0"/>
    </SOFF>
```

Here's my config.xml ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<subscriptionmappings>
<soff name="ABC">
<mandatorysoffs>
  <soff name="DEF"/>
  <soff name="GHI"/>
</mandatorysoffs>
<subscribergroup>sVOD-KidsSuite</subscribergroup>
</soff>
</subscriptionmappings>
```

Here's as far as I get, I can't seem to figure out how to check for multiple soff's within where clause, I assume I need a for-loop or something similar ...

```
For $i in $config/mandatorysoffs/soff
where ($input/SOFF/@NAME = $config/soff/@name
        and $input/SOFF/@NAME = $config/mandatorysoffs/soff/@name 
        and $input/SOFF/@NAME = $config/mandatorysoffs/soff/@name ) 

        return $config/subscribergroup/text()
```

Comment: I was totally unaware of xquery/quantified expressions. Good to know, thank you for your help. Been a huge help! -Jeremy

Answer (score 1):

You can just check for the occurrence of each `soff` from the first document in the second document and then make sure that none of them are missing (i.e. `false`):

```
xquery version "1.0";

let $chk-soffs := doc("config.xml")//soff/string(@name)
let $soffs := doc("input.xml")//SOFF/string(@name)
return

let $results := for $soff in $soffs
return
$chk-soffs = $soff
return

not($results = false())
```

or if you have access to a processor that supports XQuery 3.0:

```
xquery version "3.0";

let $chk-soffs := doc("config.xml")//soff/string(@name)
let $soffs := doc("input.xml")//SOFF/string(@name)
return

let $results := $soffs ! $chk-soffs = .
return

not($results = false())
```

Comment: Thank you for posting a solution to my problem, its much appreciated!

Comment: Most likely a copy-paste error, I think you left an extra `for` in the init value of `$results` for XQuery 3.0.

Comment: @FlorentGeorges Ah yes indeed. Thanks I corrected the code.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to return a `<subscribergroup>` value for every `<soff>` in your config for which the name of every child of `<mandatorysoffs>` exists as a `SOFF/@NAME` in the input. Using a [universal quantifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-quantified-expressions) in the `where` clause:

```
for $s in $config/soff
where 
  every $n in $s/mandatorysoffs/soff/@name
  satisfies ($n = $input/SOFF/@NAME)
return $s/subscribergroup/string()
```

Note that in your example `GHI` is a `PARM/@VALUE` so it still returns empty.

Comment: I was totally unaware of xquery/quantified expressions. Good to know, thank you for your help. Been a huge help!

Comment: @jhynes Happy to help. If this answer helped you, please up-vote and/or accept if you think it's the most correct answer...http://stackoverflow.com/tour